# Starting Keynote presenter mode without an external monitor

Tags: keynote

Before a talk, I'd like to try the presenter mode for Keynote - to get familiar with it - on my Macbook Pro, without an alternate display being attached.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keynote has this functionality built-in. In Keynote, go to the `Play` menu, then choose `Rehearse Slideshow.` You'll then have presenter mode on your single screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my adapter handy to test this, but you might be able to just plug the adapter in and have the MBP think it has a second monitor.

This definitely doesn't work with the mini display port to DVI adapter, but I seem to recall that it worked with a mini DVI to VGA adapter (or was it the DVI to VGA adapter?).